# SQL Database Design: extra table vs extra primary key column

Tags: postgresql

I want to optimize my PostgreSQL database design.

Currently I have one table with following columns:

```
name  - char(4)
color - char(6)
key   - text
value - real[]
```

- primary key consists of multiple fields (name, color, key)
- I have around 300 to 400 names.
- each name has 2000 different colors
- each color has 40000 different key-value pairs
- so each name has 2000 x 40000 = 80000000 rows
- I do not update rows
- I only insert new rows when I fill the database

The query speed is important for me:

```
SELECT value FROM table WHERE name = x AND color = y AND key = z;
```

Should I create a new table for each name instead of putting all names into one table?

Should I map the 2000 char(6) colors to 2000 smallint colors?

What can I else do to improve the database design?

Comment: Could the key/value pairs ever repeat?  That is, do the same key/value pairs recur throughout your table?  You could create separate tables for the name, color, and key/value, then create a new junction table to persist the relationships between all of them.

Comment: each key/value pair is unique

Comment: Your headed towards billions of records, and that's a lot of data, even in a lean junction table.  You can try tuning that table using indices.

Comment: If I create a new table for each name I only have 300-400 tables with 80000000 rows. I thought the primary key is already indexed.

Comment: If you always access the rows by primary key (name,color,key), then the size of the table is pretty much irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

The size of the table should not be a problem, and splitting the table into several tables will not improve the speed of your query.

If you *really* want to split the table, you should consider list partitioning, but that will only work well if all queries have `WHERE name = ...` in them. Partitioning will slow down your query, because PostgreSQL has to consider all the partitions during planning (or execution in v11).

Partitioning is only useful if you want to bulk delete data from your table and you can drop a partition to do that. It can also speed up queries that perform a sequential scan over one or a few partitions.

I would just leave the table as it is. The primary key index is already perfect for your query, and I don't think you can do better. Remember that query size does not impact query speed if you use an index.